# How do I sort a "MON_YYYY_day_NUM" time with UNIX tools?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wondering how do i sort this example based on time. I have already sorted it based on everything else, but i just cannot figure out how to go sort it using time (the 07:30 part for example).

My current code:
`sort -t"_" -k3n -k2M -k5n`   (still need to implement the time sort for the last sort)

What still needs to be sorted is the time:

Dunaj_Dec_2000_day_1_13:00.jpg
Rim_Jan_2001_day_1_13:00.jpg
Ljubljana_Nov_2002_day_2_07:10.jpg
Rim_Jan_2003_day_3_08:40.jpg
Rim_Jan_2003_day_3_08:30.jpg

Any help or just a point in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the future, this is much, **much** easier if you pick ISO 8601 `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` as your time format.

Comment: sadly it's an assignment. Spending so much time thinking about this... but i just can't seem to find a way i would understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alphabetically; 24h time with a fixed number of digits is okay to sort using a plain alphabetic sort.

```
sort -t"_" -k3n -k2M -k5n -k6  # default sorting
sort -t"_" -k3n -k2M -k5n -k6V # version-number sort.
```

There's also a version sort `V` which would work fine.

Comment: How are you ensuring that the month names are interpreted appropriately? The OP's data requires `Jan` to sort before `Feb`.

Comment: I read them by "time" to be referring to the entire datestamp, not just the time part. Which makes sense, since the time part is maybe the easiest thing here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OP has already figured that out, it's `k3n` for year, `k2M` for month, `k5n` for day, they only needed `k6` for the time.

Comment: Heh. Didn't realize GNU had `-M`. That's a huge help.

Comment: sorting by time as in the 13:00 part. What makes it hard is that you cannot use more than one field separator (-t) The code must first sort them by year if 2 or more years are the same, it sorts them by month and so on

Comment: @NickThenick You don't need to separate into fields on the colon. You can sort the whole string (e.g.) `09:25` against `11:00` and it will correctly put the earlier time first, because the default sort sorts from left to right. (Try it! If you write out a list of 24h times, alone in their own file, and sort it with no arguments to `sort`, they should be sorted in time order.)

Comment: @GKFX I think you're right, it seems to work! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit to shamelessly stealing from this answer on SO:

[How to split log file in bash based on time condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498465/how-to-split-log-file-in-bash-based-on-time-condition#60498465)

```
awk -F'[_:.]' '
BEGIN {
months["Jan"] = 1
months["Feb"] = 2
months["Mar"] = 3
months["Apr"] = 4
months["May"] = 5
months["Jun"] = 6
months["Jul"] = 7
months["Aug"] = 8
months["Sep"] = 9
months["Oct"] = 10
months["Nov"] = 11
months["Dec"] = 12
}
  { print mktime($3" "months[$2]" "$5" "$6" "$7" 00"), $0 }
'  input  | sort -n | cut -d\  -f2-
```

- Use _:.\ field separator characters to parse each file name.
- Initialize an associative array so we can map month names to numerical values (1-12)
- Uses awk function mktime() - it takes a string in the format of "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [ DST ]" as per https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html.  Each line of input is print with a column prepending with the time in epoch seconds.
- The results are piped to `sort -n` which will sort numerically the first column
- Now that the results are sorted, we can remove the first column with cut
- I have a MAC, so I had to use gawk to get the mktime function (it's not available with MacOS awk normally ).   mawk is another option I've read.